# Fetch a Pandas dataframe row based on matching condtion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fetch a row from pandas dataframe based on a condition.

```
[
    {
        "id": "ee123-abc"
    }
]
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
contract_num = 'ee123-abc'

if df.id.str.contains(contract_num).any():
    print(df[df.id == contract_num])
else:
    print("No matching contract numbers")
```

But am getting an error message that says

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I address this isue?

Comment: Your code works as expected in Python 3.9. If you remove `.any()` from `df.id.str.contains(contract_num)` you'll get your error. I can't see the issue with your code.

Comment: The provided code doesn't reproduce the issue